# trigger validation using regular expression not working for newline character

Tags: mysql

I am trying to validate inserts using a mysql-trigger. The inserts in col1 should be only numerical. It is NOT an option to define col1 as an integer in the first place. However, the validation fails if there is a newline character at the end.

Heres the table

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(col1 varchar(20), col2 int);
```

and here the trigger validator

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_numeric BEFORE INSERT ON testTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') = 0 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='non-numerical';
END IF;
END $$
```

If I try to insert a string including a newline character at the end this passes the validation, although it shouldn't in my opinion as the newline character is not numeric.

```
INSERT INTO testTable values('323423\n', 12);
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing here?

Comment: On MySQL 5.7.24 at least if I check for '1234\n' against that regexp I get the result of 0. I didn't check as a trigger but would assume it would work the same way. Seems very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to search for anything that is not a digit instead, this will return 1 if any character is *not* a digit: `REGEXP '[^[:digit:]]'`

So the `IF` clause would be

```
IF (NEW.col1 REGEXP '[^[:digit:]]') = 1 THEN ...
```

Of course you could write `[^0-9]` instead of `[:digit:]` if you don't want to use the character class

Comment: Surprisingly, this works for me. Although, I do not fully understand why the other way around fails. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

can you check in this way

```
IF NEW.col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND NEW.col1 NOT REGEXP '\n' THEN
```

---

```
with w as 
(select '1234' c1 from dual union all
 select '1234\n' from dual)
select * from w 
where c1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND c1 NOT REGEXP "\n";
```

**Result** :   1234

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36e16e1fd100e20012cec0a76555bae0)